# copy linked list in C using strdup

Tags: c

I have a linked data structure where i want to copy and save the original link. So  i could edit the original link list without affecting the copied linked list. i tried the following method, and i got segmentation fault.

```
struct link {
        char * name;
        struct link *next; 
    };


struct list{
        struct link  *first;
        struct link *last; 
    };



 struct list *list_new(){
    struct list *n = calloc(1, sizeof(struct list)); 
    return n; 
};




struct list* copyList(struct list*list){
     struct list*new = list_new(); 
     struct link *current = list -> first;
     struct link *newCurrent = new -> first; 
     struct link *p;
      if(current == NULL)
        return NULL; 


      newCurrent = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
      newCurrent = p;

      while (current != NULL) {
        p ->name = strdup((char*)current -> name); 
        p->next = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
        p = p->next;
        current = current->next;
      }

      return new;
    }
```

Comment: `newCurrent = malloc(sizeof(struct link)); newCurrent = p;` : allocate then  overwrite by uninitialize variable. Also `if(current == NULL)
        return NULL;` : occurs Memory leak.  `return new;` : Nothing assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
struct list *copyList(struct list *list)
{
    struct list *new = list_new(); 
    struct link *current = list->first;
    struct link *newCurrent = malloc(sizeof(struct link));

    if((current == NULL) || (newCurrent == NULL) || (new == NULL))
    {
        if(newCurrent != NULL)
        {
            free(newCurrent);
        }
        if(new != NULL)
        {
            free(new);
        }

        return NULL; 
    }
    else
    {
        new->first = newCurrent; 
    }


    while(current != NULL) 
    {
        newCurrent->name = strdup((char*)current -> name); 
        current = current->next;        
        if(current != NULL)
        {
            newCurrent->next = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
            newCurrent = newCurrent->next;
        }
        else
        {
            newCurrent->next = NULL;
            new->last = newCurrent;
        }
    }

    return new;
}
```

Comment: @kodper89 thanks, but i am getting compiling error on new = NULL , error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     if(current == NULL || newCurrent == NULL || new = NULL)

Comment: @user3262564 try now I had spelling mistake in new = NULL and lack of semicolon in free(newCurrent)

Comment: .@kodper89 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation 0x00000000004021b4 in copyList(list=0x6068b0) at list.c
271         new->first = newCurrent;   (gdb) p *(new -> first), Cannot access memory at address 0x0; (gdb) p *(newCurrent)
$1 = {name = 0x0, next = 0x0}. It seems some problem in this line, it does not allocate memory space

Comment: Make sure in last unallocated current you got null in current->next

Answer (score 0):

The errors in `copyList()` are:

- > ```
  >       if(current == NULL)
  >     return NULL;
  > ```

  An empty list should be allowed; the above fails to return the empty list copy.
- > ```
  >       newCurrent = malloc(sizeof(struct link));
  >   newCurrent = p;
  > ```

  As BLUEPIXY wrote: *allocate then overwrite by uninitialize variable.* Moreover, the above is waste, since there's another `malloc()` in the `while` loop.
- The undefined value of `p` is used in the `while` loop.

Corrected (still without allocation error checks):

```
struct list *copyList(struct list *list)
{
    struct list *new = list_new(); 
    struct link *current = list->first;
    struct link *newCurrent = NULL; 
    struct link **p = &new->first;  // where to place pointer to new node
    for (; current; current = current->next, p = &newCurrent->next)
    {
        newCurrent = *p = malloc(sizeof **p);
        newCurrent->name = strdup(current->name);
    }
    *p = NULL;
    new->last = newCurrent;
    return new;
}
```